# Magento 2 - How to add Extra Checkout Step after Review & Payments Section with Place Order Button

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add an additional checkout step after "review & payments" section. The requirement is to split the payment and review as a separate steps. Once the after the payment method is selected, it should navigate to the Final step "review" where all the order information has to be shown with "place order" button.

so far i have added custom step after payment step, by following the link below.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

But the Problem here is the "Place Order" Button is binded with the Payment Step, I need to move the place order button to the Last Step.

Any Help Most Appreciated!!

Comment: have you managed to add a step at last after payment?

Comment: @rameshpushparaj Have you done this?

Comment: Same problem here, some solution?

Comment: A alternative to this is adding a order summary to the success step. The place order button is binded to the payment step because it would be a problem if a customer pays and then doesn't finish the order, then the payment wouldn't belong to any order.

Answer (score 1):

Below i have add some step. please follow step

1.Create your checkout_index_index.xml file in layout folder

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendorName_PlaceOrder::css/place_order_button.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="newstep" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/js/view/newstep</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PlaceOrder/newstep</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.Create a file newstep.html in template

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/template

```
<div class="opc-block-newstep" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order newstep'" class="title"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="actions-toolbar-trigger" id="place-order-trigger-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="button action primary" id="place-order-trigger" value="Place Order" >
        <span>Place Order</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

3. Create a file newstep.js in the path

> app/code/VendorName/PlaceOrder/view/frontend/web/js/view

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/newstep',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            isVisible: function () {
                return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
            },
            initialize: function () {
                $(function() {
                    $('body').on("click", '#place-order-trigger', function () {
                        $(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );
                    });
                });
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

4.For Add terms & condition checkbox in checkout_index_index.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                            <item name="newstep" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    </item>

                                                    <item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/agreement-validation</item>
                                                    </item>

                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: The place_order_button.css file is missing in this answer

Comment: is this solution resolved your problem? actually, I have to do the exact same task